# qt c++ QDialog open new file

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

After almost a week of searching and reading qt documentation, I still can't figure out how to use QDialog to create a *NEW* file on my hard disk for writing data. I can open a file and write data if the file already exists, but if I attempt to create a NEW file, I get a message that the file does not exist. I can create a new file if I do not use QDialog by hard coding the path and file name, but would like to be able to choose the file location, and get the customary messages; for instance that the file already exists and asked if it is OK to overwrite it. Here is a snippet of my latest attempt:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            this,
            tr("Sensor data"),
            "C//",
            "Text File (*.txt)"
            );
    QFile file(filename);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());
        return;
    }
    QTextStream out(&file);

    out<<"string1";
    out<<"\n";
    out<<"string2";
    out<<"\n";
    out<<"string3";
    out<<"\n";
    out<<"string4";
    out<<"\n";
    out<<"string5";
    file.close();
}
```

Can QDialog be used for this purpose? If not, please point me to information on how it is done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use getSaveFileName instead

Comment: Wow! I was SO close! Exactly what I was looking for! How can I thank you!?!?

Answer (score -1):

In Qt exemples there is project called SDI ,  content simple window and menu and all what you need  about file : new, open, save, and save as .